# How do you query DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm on Step 5.1 of "DynamoDB's Getting Started guide" http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.JsShell.05.html#GettingStarted.JsShell.05.01 and am blocked by a non-working example.

```
var params = {
  TableName: "Music",
  KeyConditionExpression: "Artist = :artist",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":artist": "No One You Know"
  }
};

dynamodb.query(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
  else
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

The shell accepts the input but produces an Error

```
{
  "message": "There were 2 validation errors:\n* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'KeyConditions' in params\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params",
  "code": "MultipleValidationErrors",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Missing required key 'KeyConditions' in params",
      "code": "MissingRequiredParameter",
      "time": "2015-10-27T03:08:56.504Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2015-10-27T03:08:56.504Z"
    }
  ],
  "time": "2015-10-27T03:08:56.504Z"
}
```

I tried sub'ing in 'KeyConditions' for 'ExpressionAttributeValues' like...

```
var params = {
  TableName: "Music",
  KeyConditionExpression: "Artist = :artist",
  KeyConditions: {
    ":artist": "No One You Know"
  }
};

dynamodb.query(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
  else
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

...but that just produces empty results {}.  There are, of course, items in "Music" with the "Artist" attribute set to "No One You Know", so I'm kind-of lost how to proceed here.

What is the correct expression to query DDB for the value "No One You Know" in the Artist attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this is a stale "dynamodb-local" installation. `brew upgrade dynamodb-local` deployed a 2015-07-16_1.0 version of this kid and the query now works.